# Bulk data entry to store into Inventory

Tags: python, django

I am building an ecommerce website.

I was trying to implement a feature where I can allow sellers to allow bulk upload of information about their products.

The products shall have following attributes.

Product_name,product_price,manufacturer_name.....other essential attributes
product_images,product_videos

The problem i faced was to find a convenient and user-friendly way to do this.

This problem may be common and solved very early since the process of Inventory Management started on Web.

But, I still cannot figure out a way that is very easier for sellers to upload their data in bulk.

I think possible solution may be

XML/Excel/Access File + Image and Video Folders (named by ids) zipped in a tarball.

If so what would be the standard way to do it.

I am looking guide for generalized and standard solution.

Comment: Why not use a combination of Google spreadsheets and Google drive. Version control included. And you have the "power" of apps script and Drive applications.

Comment: yes, that seems to be a good idea